# How to put data in array?

Tags: php

I have a field format:

```
{"2G Network":"GSM 850","3G Network":"HSDPA 850"}
```

How to put data in array in format:

```
array(["2G Network"]=>"GSM 850", ["3G Network"]=>"HSDPA 850");
```

How to this ideas

Comment: You are looking for `json_decode()`.

Comment: @bsdnoobz I think you mean `json_decode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = '{"2G Network":"GSM 850","3G Network":"HSDPA 850"}';
$myArray = json_decode($text, true);
```

Use:

```
echo $myArray['2G Network'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = '{"2G Network":"GSM 850","3G Network":"HSDPA 850"}';

$myArray = json_decode( $data, true ); //true to make it associative array
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: The second argument of `json_decode` should be `true` to convert it to array instead of object.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

array(5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```